# How to check an empty list in Python3

Tags: list, loops, boolean, python-3.8

I am trying to check that my list is empty with the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#First we start with the empty list of "users"
user_names = []

#Run a check with if to see if the list has "users"
if user_names:
    for user in user_names:
        print("Message to user logging in.")
#The assumption is this will evaluate to False and else will execute
    else:
        print("Message when the list is empty.")
```

But when the script is executed, nothing runs and the output is blank. I'm hoping to find out:

- if this is due to an error in my code?
- or if its a bug?
- is there a better way to write this code?

My Python version is 3.8.3

Answer (score 1):

Indentation is way to relevant for python programming.

If you run the following code:

```
user_names = []
print(f"{user_names} outside the if statement.")
if user_names:
    print(f"{user_names} inside if statement.")
    for user in user_names:
        print("Message to user logged in.")
    else:
        print("Message when the list is empty.")
```

You are gonna see that the output is `>> [] outside the if statement`. What does this mean? Well, the program is skipping the `if` statement because the list is empty, that is expected. However, the `else` statement is not being read because it is inside the `if` statement. That explains why you get a blank output. So, the following code should solve the problem:

```
user_names = []
if user_names:
    for user in user_names:
        print(f"Message to {user} logged in.")
else:
    print("Message when the list is empty.")
```

Now, look at the first `print()` function inside the code. There is two changes to the original code: the first is `f` before start the string; and the second is that the user variable is now inside curly brackets: `{user}`. This two things working together makes the loop print each user names whenever applies.

You can test this shifting  `user_names = []` to  `user_names =["a", "b"]` and running the code again.

You should get:

```
>> Message to a logged in
>> Message to b logged in
```

Finally, I recommend to use a code based on the `len()` function for testing the `if` statement (you can see the documentaion [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_len.asp)). This is only for make your code more readable to other coders.

The solution code might look like this:

```
user_names=[]
if len(user_names)==0:
    for user in user_names:
        print(f"Message to {user} logged in.")
else:
    print("Message when the list is empty.")
```

Answer (score 0):

your list is empty, but not `None` (also not type boolean = False), so the check `if user_names` alway `True`.

so your code always go to the for-loop, but nothing in the list, so it print nothing.

You can check the length of your array like this instead
`if len(user_names) == 0:`